# Cannot find Wordlists in GoBuster

Tags: go

I'm new to using Go and I wanted to use GoBuster on a test website to find all the hidden directories.
I am using TryHackMe so the IP address given is for the machine.

I have Go & Gobuster installed on my PC and i'm using the default Windows command line to execute. I'm running the command line from my user profile so C:\Users\MyName and if I echo %GOPATH% on the cmd, I get C:\Users\MyName\go.

I've followed a few installation guides so far and everything has been smooth sailing but once I got to this bit it just stopped.

For some reason I can't get the wordlists to show, i'm writing;

```
 C:\Users\MyName > gobuster dir -u http://10.10.239.80:3000 -w /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/common.txt
```

The full error I keep getting is;

```
 Error: error on parsing arguments: wordlist file /usr/share/dirb/common.txt 
 does not exist: createfile /usr/share/dirb/common.txt: The system cannot 
 find the path specified.
```

The other methods I have tried are;

```
C:\Users\MyName > gobuster -u http://10.10.239.80:3000 -w /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/common.txt

C:\Users\MyName > gobuster dir -e -u http://10.10.239.80:3000 -w /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/common.txt

C:\Users\MyName > gobuster -e -u http://10.10.239.80:3000 -w /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/common.txt    

C:\Users\MyName > gobuster dir -u http://10.10.239.80:3000 -w /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/big.txt
```

I've tried to use different txt files like small/medium-3 but didn't work either.
Tried to look for answers on the internet but there doesn't seem to be much help.

Any suggestions? Would be very much appreciated.

Regards,
SM

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is problem in domain as your path to wordlist looks cool.

```
root@kali:~# gobuster -e -u http://192.168.0.155/ -w /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/common.txt
```

try again

Comment: Hi, do you know what my issue would be with the domain is? I've set up the proxy correcly as I can access the website through it. If I copy the IP:3000 to URL it loads the webpage up. Or is it a case of something like not including the port number? Thanks in advance

Comment: the error clearly shows that common.txt file doesn't exist at that address. use createfile /usr/share/dirb/common.txt to create file and then try again.

Comment: creating the file will do nothing as I'm accesssing data from the file, thanks though

Comment: check that even it exists or don't. try cd /usr/share/wordlists/dirb and then ls -la

Answer (score 1):

The path you're using to get the wordlist doesn't exist. As it is a linux path.

Furthermore I don't think any wordlists are installed on Windows by defaults.
you can download wordlists online and use them after.
Hope this help.

Comment: Just decided to install ubuntu so should be fine hopefully! I though it may be to do with the fact that im using windows cmd

Answer (score 0):

well, you have Windows, so Unix filepaths won't work (for example "usr/share"). i recommend trying to search the wordlists up in the files manually.